# Instantiate global class inside another class

Tags: php, global-variables

I need to access a class within several functions of my main class and I don't want to instantiate the class within each. I would instead like to create a global variable pointing to a new instance of Class2. How can I achieve this in PHP? Code:

```
Class Main 
{
    public $l = new Class2();

    public function f1()
    {
         $this->$l->getData();
    }

    public function f1()
    {
         $this->$l->getData();
    }
}
```

**ERROR:**

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError
(E_ERROR) Cannot access empty property
```

I also tried :

```
public $l;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->$l = new Class2();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop the dollar sign,

```
public $l;

public function __construct()
{
  $this->l = new Class2(); // no $
}
```

When access a class property you don't need the dollar sign in front of the variable.